# Dynamically build except statements in python

Tags: python

So I have multiple functions that perform different actions. Error handling is pretty much similar among functions, with slight variations though.

ErrorA and ErrorB are being handled in all functions. I would like to refactor this to avoid repeating the except clauses for ErrorA and B in every place. Is there a way in Python to get this? I do not want to change code behavior nor define nested try-except blocks. Your answers are very welcome!

```
def func_a():
   try:
       do_action_a()
   except ErrorA:
       handle_error_a()
   except ErrorB:
       handle_error_b()
   except ErrorC:
       handle_error_c()

def func_b():
   try:
       do_action_b()
   except ErrorA:
       handle_error_a()
   except ErrorB:
       handle_error_b()
   except ErrorD:
       handle_error_d()

def func_c():
   try:
       do_action_c()
   except ErrorA:
       handle_error_a()
   except ErrorB:
       handle_error_b()
   except Exception:
       handle_general_exception()
```

Comment: You can have an unrestricted `except:`, then call a function to process the exception, passing it as an argument.

Comment: You can get the exception info from `sys.exc_info()`

Comment: @TomKarzes I mean, in that case, you should use `except Exception as e: handle_generic(e)` right?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, I guess that makes more sense.  I guess the only exceptions that wouldn't catch would be ones that subclass `BaseException` directly.

Comment: Will your ErrorA,B etc. be standard exceptions? Or are you planing to do custom ones? As Exceptions are classes as well you could build handlers on a class level. But depends strongly on your actual setup.

Answer (score 0):

So, the most straightforwar way would be to refactor the handling of `ErrorA` and `ErrorB` into it's own function, something like:

```
def execute_with_a_b_handling(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    except ErrorA:
        handle_error_a()
    except ErrorB:
        handle_error_b()

def func_a():
   try:
       execute_with_a_b_handling(do_action_a)
   except ErrorC:
       handle_error_c()

def func_b():
   try:
       execute_with_a_b_handling(do_action_b)
   except ErrorD:
       handle_error_d()

def func_c():
   try:
       execute_with_a_b_handling(do_action_c)
   except Exception:
       handle_general_exception()
```

Of course, with a better name.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I quite like using context managers in this situation. These are best used where there is a point in the code from which it is worth checking the error from, and then another point where the error should be removed.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

global_errors = {}

@contextmanager
def error_handler_context(error, function):
    # Code to acquire resource, e.g.:
    global_errors[error] = function
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        # Code to release resource, e.g.:
        del global_errors[error]    

def handle_errors(function):
    try:
        function()
    except Exception as e:
        try:
            global_errors[type(e)]()
        except Exception:
            raise e


def error_1():
    print("here")

def value_error_raise():
    raise ValueError("Test")
    
def exception_raise():
    raise Exception("test Error")

with error_handler_context(ValueError, error_1):
    handle_errors(value_error_raise)
    handle_errors(exception_raise)
```

This is not a perfect solution, and there are definitely a lot of cases where this should not be used. So use caution.